# Jquery using $this in a for loop in an each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, each

Here's my code for a basic jquery image slider. The problem is that I want to have many sliders on one page, where each slider has a different number of images. Each slider has the class .portfolio-img-container and each image .portfolio-img.

Basic html setup is as follows:

```
<div class="portfolio-item"><div class="portfolio-img-container"><img class="portfolio-img"><img class="portfolio-img"></div></div>

<div class="portfolio-item"><div class="portfolio-img-container"><img class="portfolio-img"><img class="portfolio-img"></div></div>
```

And javascript:

```
 $.each($('.portfolio-img-container'), function(){


        var currentIndex = 0,
            images = $(this).children('.portfolio-img'),
            imageAmt = images.length;


        function cycleImages() {
            var image = $(this).children('.portfolio-img').eq(currentIndex);
            images.hide();
            image.css('display','block');
        }


        images.click( function() {
            currentIndex += 1;
            if ( currentIndex > imageAmt -1 ) {
                currentIndex = 0;

            }

            cycleImages();
        });


    });
```

My problem comes up in the function cycleImages(). I'm calling this function on a click on any image. However, it's not working: the image gets hidden, but "display: block" isn't applied to any image. I've deduced through using devtools that my problem is with $(this). The variable image keeps coming up undefined. If I change $(this) to simply $('.portfolio-img'), it selects every .portfolio-img in every .portfolio-img-container, which is not what I want. Can anyone suggest a way to select only the portfolio-imgs in the current .portfolio-img-container?

Thanks!

Comment: You could set relevant context using: `cycleImages.call(this);` and better would be to set logic regarding `currentIndex` inside `cycleImages()` method and then just bind it using: `images.click(cycleImages);`

Answer (score 5):

`this` within `cycleImages` is the global object (I'm assuming you're not using strict mode) because of the way you've called it.

Probably best to wrap `this` once, remember it to a variable, and use that, since `cycleImages` will close over it:

```
$.each($('.portfolio-img-container'), function() {
    var $this = $(this);                                                 // ***

    var currentIndex = 0,
        images = $this.children('.portfolio-img'),                       // ***
        imageAmt = images.length;

    function cycleImages() {
        var image = $this.children('.portfolio-img').eq(currentIndex);   // ***
        images.hide();
        image.css('display', 'block');
    }

    images.click(function() {
        currentIndex += 1;
        if (currentIndex > imageAmt - 1) {
            currentIndex = 0;
        }

        cycleImages();
    });
});
```

---

Side note:

```
$.each($('.portfolio-img-container'), function() { /* ... */ });
```

can more simply and idiomatically be written:

```
$('.portfolio-img-container').each(function() { /* ... */ });
```

Side note 2:

In ES2015 and above (which you can use with transpiling today), you could use an arrow function, since arrow functions close over `this` just like other functions close over variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just refer to `this` inside of an inner function ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback/20279485#20279485) for *a lot* more detailed explanations):

```
var self = this; // put alias of `this` outside function
function cycleImages() {
  // refer to this alias instead inside the function
  var image = $(self).children('.portfolio-img').eq(currentIndex);
  images.hide();
  image.css('display','block');
}
```